# Tornado performance evaluation

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I set the task to translate our server tornado c python on pypy. I have successfully done it. Now I need to measure what load the server will sustain self-inflicted by python and pypy. How do I measure it? You need to run a simple server and client, which sends parallel to 10,000 post requests? Or you can do it - that on another?

**Server:**

```
server = HTTPServer(app)
server.listen(8888)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

How do I send the same time 10,000 requests to the server? With the help of a tool from a tornado do it better?

Answer (score 2):

There's various tools for that: [here are some tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server_benchmarking).

Beware that this type of measurement is not trivial. You need to make sure that your clients outperform your server; when using multiple clients you need to synchronize their traffic (at the risk of introducing extra measurement noise) and you need to be very aware of any network bottlenecks.

If you're simply looking for a comparison of Tornado to its alternatives:  see [this page](http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers)